# Elements of a canvas disappearing after being redrawn

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas that I am trying to make a simple word game with.

Everything draws correctly initially, but when I try to redraw the canvas the background disappears.

html:

```
<canvas width="600" height="600" id="game-canvas"></canvas>
```

js:

```
var width = 600;
var height = 400;
var canvas = document.getElementById("game-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var scrambleWord = getScrambleOrder();

//object definitions
var game = {
    hasBegun:false,
    scrambleArr:scrambleWord.split(''),
    letterX:20,
    letterY:360
};

var startButton = {
    width:160,
    height:50,
    x:((height/2)),
    y:200,
    text:"Start!",
    color:"#90afc5"
};

//Event Listeners
function getMousePos(canvas, event) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: event.clientX - rect.left,
        y: event.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

function isInside(pos, rect){
    return pos.x > rect.x && pos.x < rect.x+rect.width && pos.y < rect.y+rect.height && pos.y > rect.y;
}


canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);

    if (isInside(mousePos,startButton)) {
        game.hasBegun = true;
    }else{
        console.log("clicked outside of button");
    }
}, false);

//Drawing
function draw() {
    //Background
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    //Initial Screen
    if (!game.hasBegun) {
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        ctx.font = "bold 50px verdana, sans-serif ";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.fillText("Word Scramble!", 70, 80);
        ctx.font = "bold 20px verdana, sans-serif";
        ctx.fillText("Arrange the words as you go!", 150, 150);
        ctx.fillStyle = startButton.color;
        ctx.fillRect(startButton.x, startButton.y, startButton.width, startButton.height);
        console.log(startButton.x);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.fillText(startButton.text, (startButton.x + 50), (startButton.y + 30));
    }

    //Game has begun - TAG BEGIN
    if (game.hasBegun) {
        for (var i = 0; i < game.scrambleArr.length; i++) {
            ctx.font = "bold 20px verdana, sans-serif ";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
            ctx.fillText(game.scrambleArr[i], game.letterX, game.letterY);
            game.letterX += 40;
        }
    }
}

setInterval(draw, 1000);

function getScrambleOrder() {
            var getScrambledWord = /[^=]*$/g;
            var url = window.location.href;
            var finalWord = url.match(getScrambledWord);
            return finalWord[0];
}
```

Why does the start button stay on the screen when the background does not?

I have tried moving where I draw the black screen into the if statement where the button is drawn, but it still disappears.

It looks like everything initially draws, then everything except the start button disappears after the canvas is redrawn once.

[Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/madamson8/fojzzj4a/1/)

Comment: Your draw function fills the background first. It does not set a fill-style, so it uses whatever is current. Do you think that perhaps the fact the background is drawn the same colour as the text could be significant? ;)

Comment: It looks like that's the issue!  I thought that the default fill-style was black, but I now that I think about it it gets set to a different color when I finish the function.  You should post this as an answer and I'll accept it.